# Homogenous recurrence representing n*Fib(n)

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

Let Fibonacci numbers be defined as usual, represented by homogeneous linear recurrence $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$, with starting coefficients $F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1$. Consider sequence $G_n = n\cdot{F_n}$, defined for non-negative integers $n$. How do I represent $G_n$ by a homogeneous linear reccurence?

Computing $G_n$ gives me a following sequence (A045925):

$$ 0, 1, 2, 6, 12, 25, 48, 91, 168, 306, 550,\cdots$$

I have been going at this question for a while, and have searched all over this website too, haven't been able to find anything. I gather that there is some relationship between general solutions and characteristic equations of $F_n$ and $G_n$, and I intuitively suspect general form to be $$nF(n) = (c_1+c_2n)(\varphi)^n+(c_3+c_4n)(1-\varphi)^n$$ But apart from that this question escapes me.

Comment: Ask [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FindLinearRecurrence%5B%7B0,+1,+2,+6,+12,+25,+48,+91,+168,+306,+550%7D%5D) or  [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A045925).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generating function for the Fibonacci numbers has denominator
$1-x-x^2$. Multiplying by $n$ should replace the denominator by its square, viz.,
$$(1-x-x^2)^2=1-2x-x^2+2x^3+x^4.$$
Therefore I'd expect $nF_n$ to satisfy the recurrence
$$a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}-2a_{n-3}-a_{n-4}.$$

Comment: Similarly, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty F_n x^n = \frac{x}{1-x-x^2}$, so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n F_n x^n = x \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{x}{1-x-x^2} \right)$

Comment: Indeed, [oeis/A045925](https://oeis.org/A045925) says `LinearRecurrence[{2, 1, -2, -1}, {0, 1, 2, 6}, 34]`.